# Binary operator expected while using diff

Tags: linux, bash, file, diff

I've jest started learning bash and I wrote a simple script, which should compare 2 files with 'diff'. When I execute this script I am getting an error: "wyjscie-rozwiazanie.out: binary operator expected".

```
#!/bin/bash
for(( i = 1;i<10; i++ )); do

    pom1="cuk$i.in"
    pom2="cuk$i.out"

    ./cuk  <cuk_testy/an/in/$pom1  >wyjscie-rozwiazanie.out

    echo "----------------------------------------------------------------"
    echo "   test nr: $i "


    
    if [ diff wyjscie-rozwiazanie.out "cuk_testy/an/out/$pom2" ]
    then
        echo "   !!!!WRONG!!!!"
        echo "   moja odp: "
        cat wyjscie-rozwiazanie.out
        echo ""
        echo "   odp prawdziwa:"
        cat cuk_testy/an/out/$pom2
        echo $DIFF
    else
        echo "   OK!"
        
    fi
    echo "----------------------------------------------------------------"
    
done
```

When I add set -x and run this script I am getting in the terminal:

```
++ (( i++  ))
++ (( i<10 ))
++ pom1=cuk2.in
++ pom2=cuk2.out
++ ./cuk
++ echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------
++ echo '   test nr: 2 '
   test nr: 2 
++ '[' diff wyjscie-rozwiazanie.out cuk_testy/Podzadanie3/out/cuk2.out ']'
./spraw.sh: line 15: [: wyjscie-rozwiazanie.out: binary operator expected
++ echo '   OK!'
   OK!
++ echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Add `set -x` before the first expression in your shell script.  This will echo all variable assignments, loop conditions, etc.  A very useful troubleshooting tool :)  I suspect the problem might be that `$pom2` contains a *SPACE*, creating *TWO WORDS* instead of one.

Comment: What @paulsm4 said. Or that `diff` can't find the second file.

Comment: I still can't find anything. The file probably exists, because  when I changed my code a little bit, I could see the content of this file on the terminal.

Comment: @paulsm4, how can I delete the space. When I do this, terminal shouts: missing `]'.

Comment: Quote the variable expansion part `if [ diff wyjscie-rozwiazanie.out "cuk_testy/an/out/$pom2" ]` ...

Comment: @Jan1984_PL: Q: Did you add `set -x`?  Q: Did you actually *SEE* a "space"?  Please "Edit" your post, and copy/paste the additional information.  To answer your question, double quotes (e.g. `"cuk_testy/an/out/$pom2"`) should do the trick :)

Comment: @paulsm4: I did, I am looking for it. I edited this post.

Comment: just `if diff wyjscie-rozwiazanie.out cuk_testy/an/out/$pom2` ... or yet better call  `cmp -s`.

Comment: @Jan1984_PL: Thank you for the update.  The problem was syntax with your "if" statement, *NOT* (as I first thought) the arguments to "diff".  SOLUTION: `if diff wyjscie-rozwiazanie.out cuk_testy/an/out/$pom2`.  REASON: the square brackets ("[]") are an alias for [test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test).  If you mentally substitute `if test  diff wyjscie-rozwiazanie.out cuk_testy/an/out/$pom2` you'll see the reason for the error.  Good question!  +1.

Comment: @paulsm4, Thanks, this problem disappeared. Now I got a new one... "No newline at end of file". I have to find sth else.